# Reverse sorting order in Photos app on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, photos, sort

the Photos app on Mac is really nice, but it shows the oldest pictures first, so I have to scroll to the bottom each time I open it... and I have lots of pictures.

So my question is: How can I reverse this order and see the newest pictures first? And can I do that across all platforms?

Thanks anyway!

Comment: http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6984032?tstart=0) that is not possible as of August 2015.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a *smart album* as shown in the animated .gif
[image]
Here are the steps:

1. File>New Smart Album
2. select *Date Captured*, *is after*, *1/1/1*
3. right click new album>sort>keep sorted by newest first